# How to import github project to stackoverflow profile?

Tags: github

I am new here in stackoverflow, and I saw this advert about importing our github project to stackoverflow profile:

[image: importing github project advert]

But really, I cannot find a way to do this. Any helps? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the banner clearly states, this is for [StackOverflow **Careers**](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), which is invite-only.